# Automatically generate lightning component on record insert

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, tooling-api

So I have created some code which essentially iterates through records on an object to map it to specific lightning components dependent on the recordtype. I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find anything about auto generating code.

Essentially what I am looking to do is when a record is inserted on my custom object I want it to automatically generate the lightning component code dependent on specific fields inserted on my object. With a view to release this on the AppExchange (Similar to DLRS).

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: DLRS uses an Apex wrapper around the Metadata API to generate and dynamically deploy triggers. It's [open source](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) if you want to look through the code - I can't say I've ever dynamically deployed a component, but perhaps someone else can answer with more detail!

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks David Ill give that a look over now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After must discussion internally it appears this 'Might' be possible through the Tooling API 
https://ashwanisoni.wordpress.com/2017/01/18/force-com-tooling-api-create-apex-class-apex-trigger-dynamically-and-updatedelete-apex-trigger-apex-class-using-tooling-api-with-rest-api/

Over the next couple of days I will be attempting to implement this solution and will update this answer with my findings.

UPDATE:
So I have implemented a basic script to generate an auradefinationbundle to hold the component. We create this using the method below:

```
 webservice static String createBundle(String sbundleName)
    {
        JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
        body.writeStartObject();
        body.writeStringField('DeveloperName', sBundleName);
        body.writeStringField('Description', 'Code Generated Bundle');
        body.writeStringField('ApiVersion', '41');
        body.writeStringField('MasterLabel', 'Test Label');
        body.writeEndObject();
        HttpRequest createReq = new HttpRequest();
        createReq.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/AuraDefinitionBundle');
        createReq.setBody( body.getAsString() );
        System.debug('JSON BODY : ' +  body.getAsString());
        createReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        createReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        createReq.setMethod('POST');
        createReq.setTimeout(30000);
        Http h = new Http();   
        HttpResponse createRes = h.send(createReq);
        System.debug(createRes.getXmlStreamReader().toString());
        String returnId = createRes.getXmlStreamReader().toString().substringAfter('id":"').substringBefore('",');
        return returnId;
    }
```

Once created the aura bundle id is returned to be used in any other methods i.e to generate the component mark up like so.

```
 webservice static void createComponent(String sBundleId)
{
    JSONGenerator body = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    body.writeStartObject();
    body.writeStringField('AuraDefinitionBundleId', sBundleId);
    body.writeStringField('DefType', 'COMPONENT');
    body.writeStringField('Source','<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" controller="CampaignUIController">MY COMPONENT</aura:component>');
    body.writeEndObject();
    HttpRequest createReq = new HttpRequest();
    createReq.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/AuraDefinition');
    createReq.setBody( body.getAsString() );
    System.debug('JSON BODY : ' +  body.getAsString());
    createReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    createReq.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    createReq.setMethod('POST');
    createReq.setTimeout(30000);
    Http h = new Http();   
    HttpResponse createRes = h.send(createReq);
}
```

All in all this can be run from the Execute Anonymous window using the follow code.

```
String bundleId = createAuraDefBundle.createBundle('automaticCreateTest');
createAuraDefBundle.createComponent(bundleId);
```

Returning the aura bundle:

[image: Created Bundle]

Hope this helps Guys :)

Comment: Yes, AuraDefinitionBundle supports create() so we can do that by using tooling api...I've done similar...please let me know if you need any help!
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_auradefinitionbundle.htm

Comment: ...have you developed the code to create Lightning component programmatically...if yes...would it be possible to share the code to create different bundles?

Comment: @AyubAnsari Not yet I have been juggling a few things here but I have this in the pipeline for early next week, so expect to be shared then.

Comment: @AyubAnsari See Above, Vote up if this helps